# Backward compatibility in IE9

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I am using windows7 which comes with IE9. My company website works with IE6 and IE7. I tried to install IE7 in windows7 but windows in not allowing me.

How can I open such websites in IE9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot install IE 7 on modern versions of Windows, but there's no reason for you to do so because you can tell IE 9 to render pages as if it were IE 7. To do this:

1. Open the desired website in IE 9.
2. From the "Settings" (cogwheel) menu, select the "F12 developer tools" option (or press <kbd>F12</kbd>).

   [image]
3. In the new pane that appears, click on the "Browser Mode" menu, and select "Internet Explorer 7".

   [image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't necessarily true.  I've been finding out from users that a page I'm working on has bugs that show up in REAL IE9 but not in IE10 running in IE9 mode.  Which really sucks.

Answer (score 1):

Click "Tools" on the top-right corner, then choose developers tools or simply press F12 on the website. You'll see a option named "Browser mode: IE9", click and change it respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to view your websites in older versions of IE? IF so, the simplest way to that would be to use IE Tester, which allows you to view websites in all versions of IE going back to V5.5. You can read more about the tool [on the IE Tester website](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)

Answer (score 0):

In IE 9 you can change the browser mode and standards using the developer tools to see what the rendering and behavior are like in IE 7 and 8.  For IE 6 you will need to use a virtualized version of Windows XP.